# WHY copy paste keyframe reset position of object to world origin?

Tags: animation, keyframes

iam using blender 3.2 and 3.5

**so i have this problem when, i am copy and paste keyframe it change the position to world origin although i already insert location, rotation and scale to the keyfame, it still change the position to world origin**.
i use to do copy paste without problem.
with duplicate (shift + D) it doing normaly.
but copy and paste is more faster and efficient than duplicate, because you don't need to drag the keyframe to your position.

i already install and uninstalling, close and open, make sure keyframe has key on the position. but it no use.

did i press wrong button ? or change some setting ?

[image: before paste]

[image: after paste]